# form still submitting even after using preventDefault and return false

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple comment form, which submits through `$.ajax`. However, I'm having some problems with it refreshing on submit.

This happens even though I am using both `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` within my submission `script`.

I have looked at every single post I can find on **StackOverflow** and even various **Fiddles**, but have come across no solutions.

This is my **JavaScript**:

```
$(".f-track-actions__form").submit(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();

    var wave = $.cookie("cv"),
        wave = eval(wave),
        waveDuration = wave.getDuration();

    var child = $(this).children(".f-track-actions__form-comment");
    var cTime = (wave.getCurrentTime() / waveDuration) * 100;
    var pD = {
        'c': comment.val(),
        'i': child.attr('id'),
        't': cTime
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "/spectrum-rr/core/_func/functions/actionTrack.php",
        data: pD,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form method="post" class="f-track-actions__form">
    <input class="f-track-actions__form-comment" type="text" placeholder="Comment on this track..." name="comment" id="c-1">
</form>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Check for error in console..

Comment: @Rayon I have. None have appeared

Comment: Can You provide html code ?

Comment: can you provide a fiddle ?

Comment: Your code should work fine. Is the event bound correctly? Are you running your code within document.ready?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes it is. will display HTML now for you all :)

Comment: As an aside I'm sure there has to be a better way of achieving what you need that using `eval()`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan for what I'm using it for, It is all that I can use at the current time.

Comment: it might be worth noting that this form is duplicated across the document through PHP.

Comment: Does the form exist when the page loads, or is it dynamically created/appended?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan dynamically created

Comment: Then see the referenced question. You can't use your event binding method for elements that don't exist when the page is first loaded.

Comment: @Barmar there are no static elements which I am able to use as an event handler. :/ most of the stuff on the site is randomly generated

Comment: @Barmar I have tried using `$(document).on('submit', '.f-track-actions__form', function(ev){` (and `$("body")`). However, I always get this error:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: wundefinedw is not defined(…)`

Comment: Sounds like you have a typo somewhere. I've never heard of `wundefinedw`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this function before and it is working with `e.preventDefaults`

```
$('#contactForm1').on('submit',function(e){
    e.preventDefaults();
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't work unfortunately :/

Comment: use this for your tag

Comment: `<form id="Form"  role="form">`

Comment: There's absolutely no difference between `$(selector).submit(func)` and `$(selector).on("submit", func)`. The `submit()` function just calls `.on()`.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html to this,

```
<form action="" method="post" class="f-track-actions__form">
    <input class="f-track-actions__form-comment" type="text" placeholder="Comment on this track..." name="comment" id="c-1">
</form>
```

The submit handler is not working, because you missed to add `action` attribute to the form

Comment: Nope. Still not working :(

Comment: can you create a pen codepen.io?

Comment: also make sure that you included the js after the html block.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're binding your button in the document ready event...

```
$( document ).ready() {
    $(".f-track-actions__form").submit(function(ev){
        ...
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no available button. The user must hit enter to submit. And, they're already within the `$(document).ready()` event

Comment: You haven't shown your code wrapped up in the document ready event. Regardless, if you're generating the form dynamically there's a chance that the document ready event runs too late and is not binding the form.  Also if there's multiple instances of the form, then there's a change that one of the other forms is not binding correctly and is somehow triggering a postback. Either way, without a way to replicate the error on a jsfiddle, I'm afraid I can't really help...

Comment: ended up fixing it :)

Comment: What's the solution? If you don't post the answer, then this question won't really help others with the same problem.